# Custom ActionLink that renders default and / or custom link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, helper

I am trying to customize an **ActionLink()** helper to render different links along with a default link to the main page. In the end, I would have a website with following rendered links:

when `@Html.MyActionLink()` is with no input parameters 
**Back to the main page**

with one set of input parameters, e.g. `@Html.MyActionLink("Go to students","Index", "Students")`
**Go to Students** | **Back to the main page**

with one set of input parameters, e.g. `@Html.MyActionLink("Go to students","Index","Students", "Go to modules","Index","Modules")`
**Go to Teachers** | **Go to modules** | **Back to the main page**

Do you think it is possible?

Thanks

EDIT:
OK. I've got a comment that it is possible etc. That's great and I can understand how to make simple html helpers by adding an extension method, for instance, but this is a little bit too complicated to me. I don't know what I should return from a static function and how to build the combined ActionLink() helper. I would be grateful for an example. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: yes look up custom html helpers.

Comment: You return HTML code from the helper, formatted however you want. You can even return combined values from `Html.ActionLink()` if you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. You will need to take it upon yourself to research how to do what you want to do. Once you make a good faith effort at writing some code, we can help you with *specific* problems/questions you have.

Comment: I understand. I couldn't work it out. I found a website [Generating Traditional URLs with ASP.NET MVC3](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/generating-traditional-urls-with-aspnet-mvc3--net-20953) that helped me a lot.